# Index hyperlink wrong jump to physical page, not the numbered page

Tags: hyperref, memoir, page-numbering, hyperlink

In the sample `memoir` document below, the `\index(two}` entry on the `mainmatter` page number 3 (which is physical page 5 of the entire document) appears in the index as

two, 3

However, the Index hyperlink for "two" jumps erroneously to physical page 3 (namely, the Contents page) instead of the expected main matter page numbered 3.

I tried this both while including the `hyperref` default option `plainpages=false` and while changing it to `plainpages=true`, but with no change in the erroneous behavior.

How can this be corrected?

```
%% file indexing-lin-err.tex
%
\begin{filecontents}{indexing-link-err.ist}
% MakeIndex style file 
item_0  "\n\\item {"
delim_0 "}, "
item_x1 "} \n \\subitem "
headings_flag 1
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  hypertexnames=false,
  plainpages=false, % no link change if use plainpages=false
  pdfpagelabels,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  linktocpage=true,linktoc=all, 
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
{\centering\Huge THE TITLE}\clearpage
{\LARGE Copyright notice}\clearpage

\pagestyle{headings}

\tableofcontents\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Preface}

\kant[1-8]\clearpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{The chapter}
\section{A section}

\kant[1]\index{one}

\kant[2-8]\index{two}
\clearpage

\backmatter

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong hyperlink jump]

**Notes:**

1. Because of the `\pagestyle{empty}`, no page numbers whatsoever appear on the title and copyright pages. Then `roman` numbers starting with `iii` appear on the Contents page and continue into the Preface. As expected, `arabic` numbers starting with `1`, appear on the `mainmatter` pages.
2. The `hyperref` option `hypertexnames=false` is included because, in my actual, book-length document, there is a "Chapter 0", and without that option hyperlinks to theorems, sections, etc., are off-by-one.
3. A potential fix described in the `memoir` documentation is to use `\begin{titlingpage}...\end{titlingpage}` for the title, etc. pages that precede the Preface. However, this results in an unwanted effect: those two pages then would not be counted at all, so that the Preface would display page number i rather than the desired page number iii.

Comment: don't use hypertexnames=false, it affects the index as the manual clearly says. Solve whatever problem you have without this option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: How else? The `hypertexnames-false` option was exactly what I've seen recommended to fix the off-by-one problem when there's a Chapter 0 (at the main matter's start, I have `\setcounter{chapter}{-1}`.